# Packer.io - dial tcp 172.X.X.X:22: connect: no route to host

Tags: ansible, packer, packer-builder

I'm using `vsphere-clone` as the builder and `ansible-playbook` as the provisioner to build my machine.

In one of my ansible tasks, I'm rebooting the machine (after installing some packages and changing network interfaces names), but sometimes my VM is getting a different IP address from DHCP and the ansible playbook cannot continue to the rest of the tasks. I tried the [`ansible.builtin.setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html):

```
- name: do facts module to get latest information
  setup:
```

But it's not refreshing the IP. Also tried reboot with `shell` provisioner instead:

```
{
  "type": "shell",
  "inline": ["echo {{user `ssh_password`}} | sudo -S reboot"],
  "expect_disconnect": true,
  "inline_shebang": "/bin/bash -x"
}
```

But the next provisioners also uses the old IP. Is there a way with Packer, to refresh the IP?